# haskell -- not understanding why this associated type example needs more inference

Tags: haskell, typeclass, associated-types

Consider the following code,

```
data MyBaseExpr α where
    ConstE :: Show α => α -> MyBaseExpr α

class Monad  => MyMonadCls  where
    type ExprTyp  :: * -> *
    var :: String -> ExprTyp  α ->  (ExprTyp  α)

expTypArg :: forall  α. MyMonadCls  => ExprTyp  α ->  α
expTypArg a = undefined

-- dummy type which will be used as an instance
newtype A  α = A ( α)
```

Then, if one tries to write an instance using the expTypeArg function,

```
instance forall . (Monad , Monad (A )) => MyMonadCls (A ) where
    type ExprTyp (A ) = MyBaseExpr
    var nme init@(expTypArg -> typb) =
        return init
```

the compiler complains

```
Couldn't match type `ExprTyp 0' with `MyBaseExpr'
Expected type: ExprTyp (A ) α
  Actual type: ExprTyp 0 α
```

But, if one adds some scoped type expressions,

```
instance forall . (Monad , Monad (A )) => MyMonadCls (A ) where
    type ExprTyp (A ) = MyBaseExpr
    var nme init@((expTypArg :: MyMonadCls (A ) =>
                   ExprTyp (A ) α ->
                   (A  α)) -> typb) =
        return init
```

then it resolves fine. What's the problem resolving `ExprTyp == MyBaseExpr` for `expTypArg`?

### edit

Thanks very much, Daniel! Here's a way to take some of the verbage out, after noticing that only the type of  need be enforced.

```
ignore_comp ::  α ->  β ->  β
ignore_comp a b = b

instance forall . (Monad , Monad (A )) => MyMonadCls (A ) where
    type ExprTyp (A ) = MyBaseExpr
    var nme init@(expTypArg -> typb) =
        typb `ignore_comp`
        return init
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExprTyp is not (necessarily) an injective type function. This means that being handed something of type `ExprType m` doesn't nail down `m` -- there may also be a different `n` such that `ExprType n = ExprType m`. This makes the type of `expTypArg` a bit tricky: it uses return-type polymorphism in the same way, e.g., `read` does, so you'll need to give extra type annotations to its result in the same situations you have to do with `read`.